# Convert Dataframe as JSON data with specified schema

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql, geojson

I select some Columns from Dataframe and I want to convert to as json(Geojson) data with specified schema and save it in Database
I use spark sql 2.3.1
I have a schema as following:

```
root
|-- features: array (nullable = true)
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | |-- geometry: struct (nullable = true)
| | | |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
| | | | | |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
| | | | | | |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
| | | |-- type: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
| | | |-- auswertezeit: string (nullable = true)
| | | |-- geschwindigkeit: long (nullable = true)
| | | |-- strecke_id: long (nullable = true)
| | | |-- verkehrsstatus: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

and the new Dataframe, that I want to save according to the schema as json data as Following:

```
 val df4 = predictions.select ( "strecke_id", "geschwindigkeit", "predictedLabel").withColumnRenamed("predictedLabel", "verkehrsstatus")
```

Comment: could you attach your data frame and schema ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to convert this dataframe df4 to JSON Data with the specified Schema and save it in HDFS?

Comment: Have you tried https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#to_json

Comment: it does not work

Comment: i tried  it with that `val selecteddata =   predictions.select(struct(array(struct(struct(array(array(array("coordinates")))) as 'coordinates)as 'geomerty), 
                                array(struct($"auswertezeit" as 'auswertezeit, $"geschwindigkeit" as 'geschwindigkeit, $"strecke_id" as 'strecke_id, $"predictedLabel" as 'verkehrsstatus)as 'properties))as 'features).select(to_json('features) as 'FeatureCollection)` but i do not get the desired result